# How to resolve this android buildtoolserror

Tags: java, android, build-tools

I get this error

```
[2014-07-11 17:50:02 - App1] Using 1.7 requires using Android Build Tools version 19 or later; currently using 17.0.0
```

when i tried to use switch with strings (have to use jre version 1.7 to do this). I read on http://shuklaxyz.blogspot.com/2014/06/eclipse-error-using-17-requires-using.html that to fix this error, you have to put this line

```
sdk.buildtools=19.1
```

in your project.peoperties folder. I tried doing that  but that didnt even work. I saw on the manifest that there nothing for build tools. Does anyone know a command i can use to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your ABT from v17 to v19? Since Java 1.7 isn't supported before v19 (according to your error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your Android Build Tools to a later version. Unfortunately like a lot of things in the Android SDK it's not obvious how exactly you do this.

- Open the Android SDK Manager
- Under Tools, tick "Android SDK Build Tools 20" (or whatever the newest version is
- Click Install Packages
- Restart Eclipse